# Difference between two dates ignoring the year

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a date field in the database called cutoffdate. The table name is Paydate. The cutoffdate is as shown below:

```
CutoffDate
-------------------------
2013-01-11 00:00:00.000
2013-02-11 00:00:00.000
2013-03-11 00:00:00.000
2013-04-11 00:00:00.000
2013-05-11 00:00:00.000
2013-06-11 00:00:00.000
2013-07-11 00:00:00.000
2013-08-11 00:00:00.000
2013-09-11 00:00:00.000
2013-10-11 00:00:00.000
2013-11-11 00:00:00.000
2013-12-11 00:00:00.000
```

I want to compare the current date with the cutoffdate (any of the 12 dates above) and then if the difference is 2 days, I need to proceed further.
This cutoffdate will remain same next year and the year after. so i need to compare the date ignoring the year part.  For example if the system date is 2013-11-09, then it should come up as 2 days. Also if the system date is 2014-11-09, then it should show as 2 days. How can this be achieved? Please help

Comment: What is the RDBMS you use? MSSQL, MySql etc?

Comment: So show the results you want from the query. Showing the sample data and then throwing a word problem down doesn't really help us visualize what results you want...

Comment: I want the date to return as int. So, in this case return 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.  It uses a Common Table Expression that returns your cutoff dates, but with the current year.  Once that is done, finding the number of days between is a simple DATEDIFF operation.

```
;WITH normalizedCutoffs AS 
(
        SELECT CAST(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar, CutoffDate, 102), 1, 4, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar)) AS datetime) AS CutoffDate 
)

SELECT CutoffDate, DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), CutoffDate) FROM normalizedCutoffs
```

Comment: Edited this slightly.  My test data was varchar, after changing to datetime to match yours an additional cast was required.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @difference int

set @difference = (SELECT ABS((MONTH(GETDATE())-MONTH(@date))*30+DAY(GETDATE())-DAY(@date)))

if(@difference>2)
begin
--Code goes here
end
```

In few words the function below

```
DAY(date)
```

it return the day of date as a int. So for today, DAY(GETDATE()) returns 26.

Comment: This seems to be partially right. I can check if(@difference = 2) which obviously serves the purpose but if i need exact difference in number of days this doesnt work. Not all months have total days as 30 days.

Comment: If you wanted only the date difference between two days, the things would have been easier. I am telling that because you could get it simply as follows SELECT DATEDIFF(day,startDAte,endDate). Please look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx. However in your case you need the difference between two datimes in days ignoring the year, if I got you right. Ignoring the year means that in case of a month like February, which has either 28 or 29 days, it couldn't be used in youor calculations, unless you use an average number of days for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) 
Try This..

```
SELECT 
     2 [Datediff]
FROM Paydate t
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(dd, t.CutOffDate)) + '/' + 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(mm, t.CutOffDate)) + '/' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())))) = 2
```

This will return 2 if any of the Cutoffdates is 2 days from todays date, otherwise it will return nothing.
**EDIT**: This is a brute force way to convert the date to the current year and then check if the `DATEDIFF` returns 2.

Comment: Again, Its not ignoring the year !